# after changing Firestore rule. i got this error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a problem on firebase user sign out. I got problem. the activity is gone. the below is the logcat from the time i pressed sign out until activity gone:

```
2020-05-02 21:35:26.229 22208-22343/com.wordpress.asayerbh V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 46660
2020-05-02 21:35:26.234 22208-22343/com.wordpress.asayerbh V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2020-05-02 21:35:26.248 22208-22343/com.wordpress.asayerbh V/FA: Activity paused, time: 37740856
2020-05-02 21:35:26.271 22208-22343/com.wordpress.asayerbh D/FA: Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
2020-05-02 21:35:26.275 22208-22343/com.wordpress.asayerbh D/FA: Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
2020-05-02 21:35:26.275 22208-22343/com.wordpress.asayerbh V/FA: Not logging ad unit exposure. No active activity
2020-05-02 21:35:26.276 22208-22343/com.wordpress.asayerbh V/FA: Not logging ad exposure. No active activity
2020-05-02 21:35:26.278 22208-22343/com.wordpress.asayerbh D/FA: Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
2020-05-02 21:35:26.380 22208-22342/com.wordpress.asayerbh V/FA: onActivityCreated
2020-05-02 21:35:26.466 22208-22343/com.wordpress.asayerbh V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 37741160
2020-05-02 21:35:26.523 22208-22343/com.wordpress.asayerbh D/FA: Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
2020-05-02 21:35:26.523 22208-22343/com.wordpress.asayerbh V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-05-02 21:35:26.527 22208-22343/com.wordpress.asayerbh D/FA: Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
2020-05-02 21:35:27.185 22208-22343/com.wordpress.asayerbh D/FA: Connected to remote service
2020-05-02 21:35:27.225 22208-22343/com.wordpress.asayerbh V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
2020-05-02 21:35:27.589 2294-2959/system_process D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe4099110, tid 2959
2020-05-02 21:35:27.590 2294-2959/system_process D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2020-05-02 21:35:31.081 22516-22556/com.wordpress.asayerbh V/FA: onActivityCreated
2020-05-02 21:35:31.301 22516-22570/com.wordpress.asayerbh I/FA: App measurement disabled via the manifest
2020-05-02 21:35:31.313 22516-22570/com.wordpress.asayerbh I/FA: App measurement initialized, version: 26001
2020-05-02 21:35:31.313 22516-22570/com.wordpress.asayerbh I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
2020-05-02 21:35:31.313 22516-22570/com.wordpress.asayerbh I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.wordpress.asayerbh
2020-05-02 21:35:31.313 22516-22570/com.wordpress.asayerbh D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
2020-05-02 21:35:31.341 22516-22570/com.wordpress.asayerbh V/FA: Detected application was in foreground
2020-05-02 21:35:31.375 22516-22570/com.wordpress.asayerbh V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2020-05-02 21:35:31.647 22516-22570/com.wordpress.asayerbh V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 37746342
2020-05-02 21:35:31.671 22516-22570/com.wordpress.asayerbh D/FA: Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
2020-05-02 21:35:31.671 22516-22570/com.wordpress.asayerbh V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-05-02 21:35:31.840 22516-22576/com.wordpress.asayerbh D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe5b26360, tid 22576
2020-05-02 21:35:31.841 22516-22576/com.wordpress.asayerbh D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2020-05-02 21:35:31.955 22516-22576/com.wordpress.asayerbh D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
2020-05-02 21:35:31.960 22516-22576/com.wordpress.asayerbh D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe5b26ae0, tid 22576
2020-05-02 21:35:31.965 22516-22576/com.wordpress.asayerbh D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2020-05-02 21:35:32.315 22516-22570/com.wordpress.asayerbh D/FA: Connected to remote service
2020-05-02 21:35:32.391 22516-22570/com.wordpress.asayerbh V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
2020-05-02 21:35:37.432 22516-22570/com.wordpress.asayerbh V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

when I use the below Firestore rule I received that error,

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

but when I use the rule below it works fine :

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {   
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2020, 5, 23);
    }
  }
}
```

My sign out code:

```
      private void signout() {

        if (user != null) {
            GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                    .requestEmail()
                    .build();

            mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();

        } else {
            finish();
        }

        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
            finish();
        }
    }
```

i tried to look for the issue. i coulnt find where is the issue. 
if any one can get the issue from

Comment: Probably unrelated, but let me point out that once you call `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();`, there's no need to call `mGoogleSignInClient.signOut()` as the user is already signed out.

Comment: I removed mGoogleSignInClient. But still same issue. Since i changed the firestore rule. The issue happen. I cant stay with old rule. Its for testing only.

Answer (score 0):

Use  - FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
There is no need calling - mGoogleSignInClient.signOut() again. 
that might probably be causing the error.